# What's a safe way to store data in Android?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, singleton

I've been using singletons to store data that is loaded when my application started.  This data is used throughout the lifetime of my app, but doesn't need to be persisted for future launches.  I've started hitting the issue though that my singletons are garbage collected and their data is wiped.  Does the singleton pattern just not make any sense on Android?  Using local storage or a local database seems like overkill, but I'm not sure what else to do to guarantee my data is safe for the lifetime of my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've started hitting the issue though that my singletons are garbage collected and their data is wiped.

No, they are not. By definition, a singleton (static data member) cannot be garbage collected.

Most likely, what you are seeing is that [your process is being terminated](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

> Does the singleton pattern just not make any sense on Android?

As a caching mechanism, it is fine.

> I'm not sure what else to do to guarantee my data is safe for the lifetime of my app

A static data member is "safe for the lifetime" of your *process*. If you want data to survive process termination, you will need to store that data in a database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other sort of file.

Comment: OK, well we may be debating semantics here.  My application hasn't been terminated and when I select it from the task list it goes to the same activity it was in before.  So Android may have terminated the process, but it's trying to restore it as if it wasn't.

Comment: They can be garbage collected as soon as all references to them are gone (Activities ending, etc). That's why they should be stored at the Application level.

Comment: @Dennis: "So Android may have terminated the process, but it's trying to restore it as if it wasn't" -- correct. That is perfectly normal behavior. The recent-tasks list, however, is not a running process list. Android terminates background processes all the time to free up system RAM for other processes. If the user returns to your app, while it is still in the recent-tasks list, Android will not only fork a process for your app, but it will try to bring up the activity the user had last been in.

Comment: @wblaschko: The OP cited "singleton". The standard Java implementation of a singleton is via a static data member. Static data members cannot be garbage collected. You do not need to use a custom `Application` object.

Comment: Sorry, I know my terminology is off.  I'm just trying to figure out how to handle the scenario where an activity is activated by Android and it doesn't have any of the data I expected it to have because of this behavior.

Comment: @Dennis: As I explained in my answer, if you want data to survive process termination, you will need to store that data in a database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other sort of file. Any singletons need to be the sort of thing that can be lazy-initialized. Again, **singletons are a cache, nothing more**. Assume that your process can go away at any moment once it goes into the background.

Answer (score 1):

Are you holding onto a reference to the singletons in the Application (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) level of the app? That should keep them persistent for the most part (unless they're byte[] or something else huge).

The safest bet, however, is to assume that data will be garbage collected and structure your code with that assumption. If it's something from the web, define an asynchronous callback to load the data and then populate your views. If it's something local that is not user-generated, use the async to grab it from disk. If it's user generated, you might need to set up a database (which you can empty when you restart the app) to keep track of data.

But, if you haven't, tried keeping references to your singletons in the Application first. Brief intro here: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: I'm not holding a reference to them in Application, I'll try that.  Is this an acceptable method or advised against?  I'm wondering if I should watch for onTrimMemory and internally reset my application to force the initial load when it's activated again.

Comment: It's an acceptable method, that way the singletons are referenced until your whole app is removed from memory (at which point, you said it's safe to wipe anyway). I usually use private static variables with getters.

Comment: This method didn't work for me.  Sadly I'll have to look for something safer like both you and @CommonsWare have suggested.